# What is a "map" in the four color theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

The four color theorem declares that any map in the plane (and, more generally, spheres and so on) can be colored with four colors so that no two adjacent regions have the same colors.

However, it's not clear what constitutes a map, or a region in a map. Is this actually a theorem in graph theory, something about every planar graph with some properties admitting a certain coloring?

Or does one really prove it using regions in the plane (which I guess we take to have non-fractal boundaries, or something). What is the precise definition?

Comment: A planar graph is a simple graph that can be drawn in the plane, so that edges between nodes are represented by smooth curves that meet only at their shared endpoints (nodes).  Such graphs have well-defined "faces" which are the regions colored under the conditions of the four color theorem, i.e. regions with a shared edge along their respective boundaries are colored distinctly.  Are these the ideas that you needed to have explained in greater detail?

Comment: Here *map* probably takes its geographical meaning, and is a loose use of words.  Adjacent regions (those that share an edge) have to have different colours.

Comment: Well, maybe. Is the theorem about all planar graphs? Or regions in the plane satisfying certain axioms? I just want to know what "map" means precisely in this context

Comment: @RichardRast: Yes, it is a theorem about all planar graphs. The wording about geographer's maps and regions is arguably a more vivid picture for laypeople to understand (and is for that reason beloved by popularizers), but the actual mathematical content is in terms of "every planar graph".

Comment: Although we only need to consider finite planar graphs to establish the four color theorem, it holds (perhaps surprisingly) even for planar graphs with countably many nodes and regions.

Comment: @hardmath: Uncountably many edges and vertices too, as long as every finite subgraph is planar.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I don't think we can have uncountably many regions!

Comment: @hardmath: The geometric interpretation breaks down in this case -- but the theorem does still hold in the sense that there's a valid four-color assignment to any graph whose every finite subgraph is planar.

Comment: I guess this is a separate question, but is there a greedy-type algorithm which accomplishes this? I assume the infinite and uncountable versions follow from the original and Zorn's lemma and some sort of greedy-ness

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  I agree... compactness !!

Comment: Is being planar a first order property?

Comment: @RichardRast: No, being planar is not a first-order property in the setting where a graph is a structure and all you have is an adjacency predicate. But that's not the setting of the compactness argument I and hardmath are talking about -- instead each graph becomes its own _theory_ with a constant letter for each vertex, and a _structure_ is then a color assignment for that particular graph.

Comment: That's a clever argument, excellent!

Comment: Actually, if a map "can be colored with four colors so that no two regions have the same colors," then the map has at most four regions. Did you mean to say "***adjacent*** regions"?

Comment: Yes, certainly. It seems everyone else just autocorrected this in their minds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a formal statement. Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite planar graph with vertices $V$ and edges $E$. It is possible to find a collection $P=\{S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4\}$ of dijoint subsets of $V$ such that $V=S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3\cup S_4$ and for every $a,b\in S_i$, there is no edge in $E$ joining $a$ and $b$.

The map is the graph, and regions are the vertices.

Answer (score 5):

The theorem is a statement about planar graphs.  In the application to geography, you have a finite collection of "countries" (disjoint connected open subsets of the plane with, let's say, piecewise-smooth boundaries).  Two countries are considered to be adjacent if the intersection of their boundaries has nonzero length.  You then consider the graph with vertices corresponding to countries and edges between adjacent countries.